# Possible to override the context.write() method in ReduceContext?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Using 0.20.2...

Is it possible to override the `context.write()` method in `ReduceContext`?  I have an entire set of Reducers that I would like to all use a specific function just before every `context.write()` but I don't want them to worry about that logic, just to have it handled transparently.

For instance:

```
Iterator<Text> vit = values.iterator();

if (trans2 != null) {
    key = (Text) trans2.transform(key);
}

while (vit.hasNext()) {
    Text item = vit.next();
    if (trans1 != null) {
        item = (Text) trans1.transform(item);
    }
    context.write(key, item);
}
```

The logic before/after the write is often different, and there may be writes that happen in different cases.  I want to move the if->transform functionality out to the write() function so I can just call `context.write(a,b)` instead of `if (trans1 !=...`.

My end-goal is something like this:

```
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Iterator<Text> vit = values.iterator();

    while (vit.hasNext())
        context.write(key, vit.next());
}
```

With the write() method override:

```
public void write(Text key, Text val) {
    if (trans1 != null)
        val = trans1.transform(val);
    if (trans2 != null)
        key = trans2.transform(key);
    super.write(key,val);
}
```

or something similar.

Comment: Where is the trans1 & trans2 coming from? Is it something you get out of the key? Basically it sounds like you want to take the code from your Reducer, put it into the ReduceContext.write(), and then use the Identity Reducer.

Comment: The trans1 and trans2 variables are part of an custom class that extends Reducer which all of the reducers I've written implement.  Depending on command-line parameters, sometimes the key, key and value, or just the value will be transformed into a different format based on the Transformer stored in trans2 (for the key) or trans1 (for the value).

Comment: Is there anything else at all that you are doing in your Reducer? Because otherwise it basically sounds like you're trying to move the code that belongs in your reducer to the ReducerContext.write(). Why not simply create a single function that you pass the out Key & Value & Context, and have that function do the if/else stuff. Much, much easier than trying to override the ReducerContext.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing for the time being.  The thing is I have many reducers and will be writing more.  Which reducer gets used is determined by a parameter from the command line, so I was trying to make it a bit more extensible for my purposes.  Seems to work for now, thanks.  :)

Comment: So create a base-class that extends Reducer, and every single sub-class needs to use that base class's write() function.

Comment: You could implement/extend the OutputFormat as well... that comes close to overwriting the write() method...

Answer (score 1):

I would look at overriding the OutputFormat class you're using.  OutputFormat has the responsibility of being able to answer a RecordWriter that does the actually writing of data.  It seems you should be able to write a subclass of the current RecordWriter whose implementation of write(key,value) performs the common actions before invoking super.write(key,value).  Make your OutputFormat subclass answer the RecordWriter subclass.